# Module not found Error when using Google Search API (SERPAPI)

Tags: python, google-api, google-search-api

When I run this example code on my local machine:

```
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "secret_api_key",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "Coffee",
  "location": "Austin, Texas, United States",
  "google_domain": "google.com",
  "gl": "us",
  "hl": "en"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
```

I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'serpapi'
```

I can't find anything on Google/Bing search nor the documentation on how to go about installing this module or where it is even located. It does not respond to a pip install.

Answer (score 16):

Use can use the below command to solve the above issue \

```
pip install google-search-results
```

[You can find more details on the GitHub link](https://github.com/serpapi/google-search-results-python)

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue even after installing google-search-results

Problem: the selected interpreter on pycharm was on a different virtual environment that did not have Google-search installed

Solution: on your IDE add/select interpreter from working directory/virtual env where google-search-results was installed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).